# How can I check if a file is being used by other application?

Tags: ruby, linux

I need to process a video file, and I need the file to be completed before I open it. So I need to check if the file is opened or not before processing it, but opened by another process. Any idea how to check this? I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without any additional gems, a slightly wasteful way might be:

```
if %x[lsof -F n].split("\n").grep(/yourfilename/).empty?
  # all clear
else 

end
```

Or

```
if system %Q[lsof #{filename}] 
  # still open..
else 
  # all clear
end
```

Or, ignore my hacked suggestion and use a gem for this: https://github.com/jordansissel/fosl

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to checkout `man lsof` if you are using the `%x` or `system` hacks...