# Rails 4: Tempfile.read returns no data on second call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, temporary-files

I use a `before_validation` callback to save data from a file input.

```
def attach_document
  if id_document_file
    self.id_document = Document.create(:binary_data => id_document_file.read, :filetype => id_document_file.content_type, :filename => id_document_file.original_file, :filesize => id_document_file.size)
  end
end
```

`id_document_file` is defined via `attr_accessor` and fed by the controller. The problem is that the `before_validation` sometimes gets called twice. The first time everything works as expected. But on the second call the `read` method returns no data. Strangely, `content_type`, `original_file` and `size` return the correct values.

This is how the SQL of the second call looks like:

```
SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "documents" ("binary_data", "created_at", "filename", "filesize", "filetype", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["binary_data", "<0 bytes of binary data>"], ["created_at", Mon, 13 Oct 2014 16:39:57 CEST +02:00], ["filename", "sample.pdf"], ["filesize", 236991], ["filetype", "application/pdf"], ["updated_at", Mon, 13 Oct 2014 16:39:57 CEST +02:00]]
```

I was thinking about using the file size as a workaround (`if id_document_file.size == 0`) to stop code execution but this obviously doesn't work since the `size` method returns the correct file size. But the main question is: Why doesn't the second call return any data?

**Update:**

It should be worth noting that I save the model from two different controllers. One is the `users` controller and the other one is the `addresses` controller. The relationship between the models is the following:

*User*

```
has_one :address
```

*Address*

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :id_document, :class_name => 'Document'
```

When I call `@address.save` from the addresses controller the callback gets called once. However, if I call `@user.save` from the users controller (with `@user.build_address(user_params[:address_attributes])` before) the callback gets called twice.

The above mentioned callback is in the 'Address' model.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are triggering the before_validate with your persistence call as well, thus why the reason this is being called **twice**:

The following triggers the callback the second time around as well:

```
self.id_document = Document.create(:binary_data => id_document_file.read, :filetype => id_document_file.content_type, :filename => id_document_file.original_file, :filesize => id_document_file.size)
```

I'm also assuming that because you might be within the same call stack, there is a lock on that file (since it's being still held on by the first call to file.read?)

I would try to stop this duplicate unintentional behavior to begin with since it looks like that is your issue right now.

If you really want to dig down, and check whether that's the case, please refer to the following SO post:

[How can I check if a file is being used by other application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650314/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-being-used-by-other-application)

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect my Models and Controllers. I don't think that Document.create triggers the callback in the Address model. If that would be the case then the callback would have to be triggered always twice. But when I call @address.save it is not.